# Gnuplot rowstacked histogram plot with black and white hatch patterns

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I have to create Graphs like this image below, I tried to use gnuplot and zplot to create this, but the patterns are not as expected. Did someone know some library or anything to create this pattern(as image bellow). I appreciate for that. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the following histogram type with different fill style patterns

For example if you would want a black&white stacked histogram, then you could create them by doing the following:

```
file1 = 'hist1.dat'

set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstack
set style fill pattern

set xtics border in scale 0,0 nomirror rotate by 90  offset character 0, -6, 0
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute

set key outside right top vertical Left
set key samplen 2.5 spacing 0.85

set ylabel "Cost BreakDown (%)" font ",18" offset character 2.5,0,0

 plot newhistogram , file1 u 2:xtic(1) t "Math" lc rgbcolor "black" lt 1 fs pattern 1, '' u 3 t "Innvocation" lc rgbcolor "black" lt 1  fs pattern 2
```

where the contents of file1 could be like this

```
Read-GetAttr 19 12 
Read-If-Mod 47 23
```

The above will render the following graphic:

[image]

You can further add more layers on the stack by having the corresponding data and changing the fillstyle pattern `fs`. Further you can also change them to coloured histograms by using different `rgbcolor` values

Posting this here in case this may be useful for someone else in the future:

I also pulled up some work that I did previously, You can download a complete working example of coloured stacked Histograms with data files and gnuplot script from the following link:

[Coloured Stacked Histograms Working Example](http://nsl.cs.usc.edu/~zahaib/misc/)

Comment: @indi60 Note, that the patterns may vary a bit depending on your output terminal. Use the `test` command (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19420678/2604213) to see the available patterns.

Comment: @Christop brings up a good point. I should add that the plot above was generated by output terminal set to `set term pngcairo`, you could use others such as `set term post eps` according to your need.

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar thanks for explanation. Yes I understand to created it now. But here, gnuplot only have 8 pattern. what do you suggestion if we have more that 8 legend.

Comment: @Christoph, yes I am doing what you suggest. but still need more pattern option for this. thanks

Comment: You may want to use colours in addition to the fill style patterns in order to distinguish them or try a different output terminal which may allow more than 9 patterns.

Comment: I know, that the `lua tikz` terminal has 12 patterns, see [Fill bars in gnuplot with dots or other patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23034300/2604213) for an example, also about customizing the fill patterns.

Comment: Was anyone able to reproduce the exact same patterns presented in the image with the eps or pdfcairo terminal ? Because I cannot ...

Comment: @ValerioSchiavoni with `set term post eps color` I'm getting exactly the same pattern on an eps.

Comment: @ValerioSchiavoni Ahh I see, I was referring to my solution. Haven't checked the patterns in the original image, not sure if the original image was generated using Gnuplot in the first place. I guess only OP can answer that.