# Trouble plotting inequalities and controlling linetype and color/pattern of fill

Tags: excel, vba, styles, gnuplot, inequalities

As part of a larger project in which VBA creates worksheets using excel data and a word template I am learning gnuplot which VBA will also control.

I am trying to plot 2 functions in the same graph and shade a side. I would like for the function lines to be black or be able to specify. I would also like to specify whether the line is solid or dashed. I have sent a picture of the desired result produced through another program which is not open source so I can't control it. And I sent my best code yet. I am gratefu for any help.

I have searched the web and gnuplot documentation but nothing addresses this.
`

```
reset session
set grid ls 100 lc black
set grid x,y back
set style fill transparent solid 0.1
set xzeroaxis linetype 3 linewidth 2.5
set yzeroaxis linetype 3 linewidth 2.5
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]

f(x) = -2*x+7
g(x) = (0.6)*x-2

plot f(x) w filledcurves x1 lc "white", \
     f(x) w filledcurves x2 lc "green", \
     f(x) w l, \
     g(x) w filledcurves x1 lc "yellow", \
     g(x) w filledcurves x2 lc "white", \
            g(x) w l
```

Desired result

[image]

Result

[image]

I tried the code sent above and made a lot of progress but still lacking the control over color and fill

[image]

[Desired Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOw0l.png)

Comment: What is the difference of your 3 graphs? Maybe I missed a detail, could you please point to it and explain the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't fully understand your problem.
If you want black dashed lines, simply specify it, e.g. `w l lc "black" dt 2`.
What is the reason that you are filling with white, to avoid transparent background?

**Script:**

```
### semitransparent filledcurves and dashed lines
reset session
set grid ls 100 lc black
set grid x,y back
set style fill transparent solid 0.1
set xzeroaxis linetype 3 linewidth 2.5
set yzeroaxis linetype 3 linewidth 2.5
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]

f(x) = -2*x+7
g(x) = (0.6)*x-2

plot f(x) w filledcurves x2 lc "green", \
     f(x) w l lc "black" dt 2 lw 1.3, \
     g(x) w filledcurves x1 lc "yellow", \
     g(x) w l lc "black" dt 3 lw 1.3
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:** (pattern overlay)

Unfortunately, fill patterns in gnuplot are [rather limited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547501/7295599). You cannot freely define the angle, density or thickness of the hatch lines, unless you don't fear [the one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63471784/7295599) or [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73581200/7295599) complicated workaround.
Furthermore, I don't know if there is a better way to set the background of a pattern fill other than to plot two filled areas on top of each other. However, then you will have the problem of the correct pattern/color in the legend. I guess this might be complicated to achieve (maybe with multiplots).

**Script:**

```
### semitransparent filledcurves with patterns
reset session
set grid ls 100 lc black
set grid x,y back
set style fill transparent solid 0.1
set xzeroaxis linetype 3 linewidth 2.5
set yzeroaxis linetype 3 linewidth 2.5
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]

set key out

f(x) = -2*x+7
g(x) = (0.6)*x-2

plot f(x) w filledcurves x2 fs transparent pattern 5 lc "black" notitle, \
     f(x) w filledcurves x2 fs lc "green", \
     f(x) w l lc "black" dt 2 lw 1.3, \
     g(x) w filledcurves x1 fs transparent pattern 4 lc "black" notitle, \
     g(x) w filledcurves x1 fs lc "yellow", \
     g(x) w l lc "black" dt 3 lw 1.3
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This has been very helpful. I have been teaching myself gnuplot by trial and error coding in a terminal. I've read books and searched for days now. I forgot why I made one side of the plot white but I think it was so that the overlap region would appear. I am looking for a clear explanation of gnuplot syntax.

Comment: If I may trouble you one more time. I would like to "shade" with pattern fill because most of my students will only be able to print in grayscale. When I "set style fill" to pattern only one line is pattern filled. Thank you so much.

Comment: I didn;t mean to upload the same image 3 times. There is no difference. I've uploaded desired image, but the image is moot at this point since the only thing missing now is the pattern fill. I cannot find any explanation as to how to pattern fill each line.

Comment: Thank you very much. You've helped so much.